# Toolbar Menu button seems to look disabled

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview

## Overview

On macOS, in a `NavigationSplitView` when the menu button is added to the detail view toolbar, it seems to look disabled (refer to steps to reproduce)

## Question:

- Is there a way to not look disabled (2nd time the sidebar cell is tapped)?

## Environment

- Xcode: 14.1 beta 3 (14B5033e)
- macOS: 13.0 Beta (22A5365d)

## Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedNumber: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(0..<100, selection: $selectedNumber) { number in
                Text("cell \(number)")
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Menu {
                            Button("aa") {}
                            Button("bb") {}
                        } label: {
                            Label("Add Bookmark", systemImage: "book")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the project on macOS
2. Select cell 0 on the sidebar
3. Click on the book toolbar button and notice the menu appear
4. Select cell 1 on the sidebar

## Expected Behaviour

After step 4, the book toolbar button should look prominent (like it is enabled)

## Actual Behaviour

After step 4, the book toolbar button looks like it is disabled.

## Screenshot

[image: Toolbar button looks disabled though it is not]

## Feedback

- I have filed a feedback, hope it gets fixed.
- It might help if more feedbacks are filed as it might help get noticed

Comment: Same, I also filed as FB10950757.

Comment: Some problem. And do you also see the following behaviour: sometimes, the menu button does show as enabled, but in that case it still doesn't show a hover effect like regular buttons do. It's curious because in Apple's apps, e.g. Finder, this works (hover on menus, not only buttons) but I guess they don't use SwiftUI.